# Adding constraints in onLayout for a ConstraintLayout not working inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` to list items. And each item in the `RecyclerView` is a subclass of `ConstraintLayout`. I tried to add some constraints using `ConstraintSet` in `onLayout` and the `onMeasure` even in `onDraw` functions in the subclass (Each cell in the recyclerview). The code only executing but not reflected in the view.

[Here is the output of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JFb6.png)

```
    val redView = this.valueView.id
    val parent = this.id
    val greenView = this.diffView.id

    val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
    constraintSet.clone(this)
    constraintSet.connect(redView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, parent, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 30)
    constraintSet.connect(redView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, greenView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 100)
    constraintSet.connect(greenView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, redView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 20)
    constraintSet.connect(greenView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, parent, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
    constraintSet.applyTo(this)
```

Comment: Could you paste layout code where the recycler view is? (Maybe event the layout code for view holder)

Answer (score 0):

Using `this.id` as a reference to the parent does not seem to work. Instead, use the constant `ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID`. Your `constraintSet` would look as follows:

```
val constraintSet = ConstraintSet()
constraintSet.clone(this)
constraintSet.connect(redView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 30)
constraintSet.connect(redView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, greenView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, 100)
constraintSet.connect(greenView, ConstraintSet.LEFT, redView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, 20)
constraintSet.connect(greenView, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
constraintSet.applyTo(this)
```